# How to check if a file exists in webroot directory in cake?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to check if a file exists in the webroot directory.
I am using file_exists but I am having problems with windows/linux file paths.

```
$file = WWW_ROOT . 'img/uploads/file123.jpg';

file_exists($file);  //false
```

'$file on windows:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\blah\app\webroot/img/uploads/file123.jpg
```

'$file on unix:

```
/home/blah/webroot/img/uploads/file123.jpg
```

Is there a way to check if a file exists that works on both systems? I could check the system and str_replace the slashes but maybe there is a better way?

Comment: The slashes dont matter and will work on both systems. Try it and you will see that this is the case.

Comment: @mark yes I tried it, you are right! my path was wrong. It works also if the slashes are mixed. At least in windows, didnt check it on linux yet.

Comment: In the end it's just cosmetics.

Comment: is file_exists they way to do it in cake?

Comment: @khany file_exists works just fine but cakephp also has its own..: File::exists();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a constant called `DS` (Directory Separator)

Try with

```
$file = WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'uploads' . DS . 'file123.jpg';
```